# Java how to determine application directory when creating simple installer

Tags: java, installation

I need to create a <del>log</del> file in application directory. Currently I'm using hard-coded absolute path, like

```
public class Transformer
{
  static String LOG_DIR = "ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_THE_APPLICATION_DIRECTORY";
  File log = new File(log_DIR, "log");
}
```

If someone else have my code, he will has to go the source code, change the LOG_DIR and then recompile. I just know a little about GNU *make*. My question is, how can I create a "installer" that works like:

```
./config
make install
```

and what's the standard/better way of achieving this?

Currently I have:

1. String path = Transformer.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
2. [Best way to load application settings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161031/best-way-to-load-application-settings)

With 2, I think I can use a shell script to generate a .properties file.

#### update

Sorry about the confusing "log file", but I actually mean a regular file, it just happen to containing some sort of log information.

Comment: Consider using logback instead of log4j as it can find its configuration file in the classpath (i.e. inside your jar as opposed to a physical file).  If you use slf4j already as the logging API it is trivial to switch.

Comment: Did you ever try `new File("./relative/path")`?

Comment: @Njol yep, but this will create file relative to working directory, not to application directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the "app.logs.dir" property on application start and refer to it in the log4j configuration:

```
main(String[] args) {
  ...
  final String appRootDir = /* Detect app location. */;
  System.setProperty("app.logs.dir", appRootDir);

  // Now we can use the logger.
  ...
}
```

And in "log4j.properties":

```
 log4j.appender.filelog.file=${app.logs.dir}/myapp.log
```

**UPDATE**

Option #1, the `getProtectionDomain()` one, might not work depending on the JVM's `SecurityManager` settings so *the best way* probably is option #2 - your installer script should store the application installation location in the application configuration file.

And to keep the number of component references low you can read the configuration file into `System` properties just like I showed above.

```
File log = new File(System.getProperty("app.logs.dir"), "log");
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusing "log file", I have update my question.